# Minimizing Integral - Euler-Lagrange

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations

The question is to find the minimum value of the integral $$ \begin {aligned}\mathcal {I} [y] &=\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2} y'^2 + 1 - \cos y \; \mathrm d x  \\ \quad y(-\infty)&=0, \quad y(\infty)= 2 \pi \end {aligned} $$ I have tried applying Euler-Lagrange explicitly to obtain the equation $ y'' = \sin y $ but this doesn't seem to be much help. Since the integral has no explicit $x$-dependence, I applied the Beltrami identity to show that $$- \dfrac{1}{2} y'^2 + 1 - \cos y = C$$ for some real constant. Since the boundary conditions are finite at infinity, it follows that $y'$ goes to zero at infinity (assuming $y$ is "nice enough"), so plugging in our boundary conditions shows that $ C = 0 $. Going back to our original form, we find that most things cancel out and we are left with $$ \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} y'^2 \; \mathrm d x $$ and I'm not sure where to go from here. I've tried using integration by parts on this term to give $$ \int_{- \infty}^{\infty}y'^2 \; \mathrm d x = \bigg[ yy' \bigg]^{\infty}_{-\infty} - \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} yy'' \; \mathrm d x $$ and I think the first term drops out due to the boundary conditions but that still leaves the second term which I'm not sure how to deal with.

Comment: I'd try changing variables $y=y(x)$, $dy=y'(x)dx=\sqrt{2(1-\cos(y))}dx$.

Comment: I've tried rearranging the expression obtained from applying Beltrami for $y'^2$ and plugging that back in for the last step, but then we're left with an integral of $y$ w.r.t. $x$. I've also attempted solving for $y$ in terms of $x$ explicitly using Wolfram and that doesn't seem to be much help either

Comment: Writing $\theta = y-\pi$, we find that $\theta'' = -\sin\theta$, which describes the [*motion of pendulum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)). This means that $\theta$ must be periodic modulo $2\pi$, and hence $y'$ is periodic as well. So the integral diverges to infinity unless $y'$ is identically zero. Perhaps this implies that the infimum of the integral is not achieved by any function.

Comment: My thoughts were similar in that we are integrating a strictly positive quantity so the result must be positive, and from the boundary conditions clearly the derivative cannot be identically zero but from the way the question is worded it suggests the answer is a numerical value. Perhaps the problem lies in the boundary conditions on $y'$?

Comment: Some function gives finite value to the integral, so the infimum must exist in $[0, \infty)$. My concern is the possibility that there is no minimizer of the integral. My guess is that the pendulum started at almost the top of the cycle and making one swing back to the top would provide an approximate minimizer.

Comment: Well, the Euler-Lagrange equation appears to have a solution (admittedly not a very pleasant looking one) so would that not be sufficient for an extremal? I'm not sure how the integral can achieve an infimum without choosing a corresponding function

Comment: @backstrapp: solutions to the EL equation need not be minimizers, much like critical points of multivariable functions need not be minimizers. I find Sangchul Lee's argument against the existence of minimizers convincing. Moreover, if solutions to $y''=\sin y$ need be periodic, then they cannot satisfy the given boundary conditions. So there are no solutions to the EL equations either.

Comment: Right, I don't understand what is meant by "the integral has a finite infimum but it remains the possibility of not having a minimizer". Surely the minimizer is just the function corresponding to this infimum?

Comment: Let me take back my previous claim; It seems that we indeed have a minimizer. I feel sorry for causing a confusion.

Comment: @backstrapp: Concerning your last comment, that is "Surely the minimizer is just the function corresponding to this infimum? ". Consider the function $I(x)=(1+x^2)^{-1}$ for $x\in\mathbb R$. The infimum of $I$ is $0$ but there exists no point $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $I(x)=0$, that is, there exists no minimizer. The analogous phenomenon may easily happen for integral functionals, too. HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from my last step, I solved for $ y' $ using the Beltrami identity and then rewrote the integral as $$ \begin{align} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y'^2 \; \mathrm d x &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sqrt{2 ( 1 - \cos y )} \; \dfrac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x} \; \mathrm d x \\ \\ &= \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \sqrt{2 (1 - \cos y )} \; \mathrm d y \\ \\ &= \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \sqrt {2} \sqrt {2 \sin ^2 \frac {y}{2} } \; \mathrm d y \\ \\&= \int_0^{2 \pi} 2 \sin \frac{y}{2} \; \mathrm d y \\ \\ &= \bigg[ -4 \cos \frac {y}{2} \bigg]^{2 \pi}_{0} \\ \\ &= 8 \end{align}$$ eliminating the need to explicitly find the minimizer.

Comment: This is very interesting, but I do not understand two things. 1) How can you be sure that $y'\ge 0$? You need this to solve for $y'$ in the equation $(y')^2=2-2\cos y$ that you obtain from translation invariance. 2) How can you be sure that a minimizer exists? A priori, the functional $I$ could be devoid of minimizers, or even of critical points; the latter scenario would occur if the boundary value problem $$\begin{cases} y''=\sin y \\ y(-\infty)=0 \\ y(\infty)=2\pi\end{cases} $$ had no solutions.

Comment: For 1), I don't think it matters since we are dealing with the integral of $y'^2$, so clearly any negative answer for the minimum must be incorrect. I'm not so sure about point 2) other than the way in which the question was worded suggests that there is a definite answer. I asked my professor about any necessary conditions for the existence of minimizers and he mentioned something about convexities, but I don't think this is covered at my current level.

Comment: For 1), I agree with the result, but I do think that you should provide more justification. You wrote $y(x)=\sqrt{2-2\cos y}$, but it could equally well have been $$y(x)=\begin{cases} -\sqrt{2-2\cos y}, & x\le 0 \\ \sqrt{2-2\cos y}, & x>0, \end{cases}$$ for example. How can you exclude that? Your argument that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty y'^2 \ge 0$ is not sufficient, the integral may be positive even if the integrand is negative at some points.

Comment: Anyway, I agree that $y'>0$ at all points, as a consequence of the differential equations satisfied by $y=y(x)$. Indeed, by Beltrami's identity, if $y'(x_0)=0$ at a point $x_0$ then $y(x_0)=2k\pi$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$. But then, by the uniqueness theorem for ordinary differential equations, we should have $y(x)=2k\pi$ for all $x$, because the constant function $2k\pi$ is a solution to the Euler-Lagrange equation $y''=\sin y$. This would contradict the boundary conditions. Therefore it is either $y'>0$ or $y'<0$, but the latter contradicts boundary conditions too.

Comment: (In any case, good answer, +1).

Answer (score 3):

Consider the functional $I$ on the space of $C^1$-functions $y$ satisfying $y(-\infty)=0$ and $y(+\infty) = 2\pi$ defined by

$$ I(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \frac{y'(x)^2}{2} + 1 - \cos y(x) \right) \, dx. $$

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have

\begin{align*}
I(y)
&\geq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 2\sqrt{ \frac{y'(x)^2}{2} (1 - \cos y(x)) } \, dx \\
&\geq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sqrt{2(1-\cos y(x))} \cdot y'(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{2(1-\cos y)} \, dy
= 8.
\end{align*}

Now let us examine whether there is a function satisfying $I(y) = 8$. If this holds, then the above inequalities are saturated and hence yields equalities. By the equality condition of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, this implies that

$$ \frac{y'(x)^2}{2} = 1-\cos y(x) \qquad \text{and} \qquad y'(x) \geq 0, $$

which is then equivalent to

$$ y'(x) = \sqrt{2(1- \cos y(x))}. $$

This equation can be solved by the separation of variables technique to yield

$$ y(x) = 4\arctan(e^x). $$

With this function we obtain

$$ I(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{4}{\cosh^2 x} \, dx = 8. $$

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I'm not sure how you managed to determine the second constant of integration using the given boundary conditions?

Comment: @backstrapp, To be honest, any translate of a minimizer is also another minimizer, which means that $$ y(x) = 4 \arctan(e^{x+c})$$ a minimizer for any choices of $c\in\mathbb{R}$. I just focuses on the existence of minimizer, but perhaps my wording is misleading that it would seem to claim the solution $y(x) = 4\arctan(e^x)$ is a unique choice, which is of course not.

Comment: Ah I see, I figured out how to approach the question without explicitly solving for the minimizer but seeing this approach was helpful too. Is that a more general principal or only applicable due to the infinite limits in this case?

Comment: @backstrapp, Perhaps it is best if we need not solve the equation explicitly. I just needed to convince myself that at least a minimizer exists from a direct computation. Indeed, if the problem was posed with a strange boundary condition like $y(-\infty) = 0$ and $y(\infty) = 2018\pi$, there will be no minimizer because any solution of the Euler-Lagrange equation should yield $y(\infty) - y(-\infty) = 2\pi$.

Comment: I'm not sure about how you attained that last equality. To me at least, it  doesn't seem obvious that there are such constraints on the extremal $y(x)$ as it tends to infinity, applying EL directly appears to result in some kind of elliptic integral.

Comment: @backstrapp, The equation itself can restrict the properties of a solution. A simple example is that any solution of the equation $y' = y$ must satisfy $y(-\infty) = 0$ because we know that $y(x) = Ce^x$ is only possible form of a solution. Similarly, any minimizer must solve $y' = \sqrt{2(1-\cos y)}$ and its solution is only of the form $y(x) = 4\arctan(e^{x+c}) + 4\pi n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$. This fact reveals the restriction $y(\infty) - y(-\infty) = 2\pi$ which was hidden before solving the equation explicitly.

Comment: @SangchulLee: Therefore, the claim you made in a previous comment that solutions to the pendulum equation $y''=\sin y$ must be $2\pi$ periodic is false, if I am not mistaken. For example, $y(x)=4\arctan(e^x)$ must solve the pendulum, because it solves $y'=\sqrt{2(1-\cos y)}$ that differentiated gives $y''=\sin y \sqrt{2(1-\cos y)}^{-1} y'=\sin y$. However that function is not $2\pi$ periodic. (This is not to criticize, I really appreciate your contributions to this question).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, Yes, I am aware of that now. And I was surprised that this kind solution can exist. I knew that the motion of pendulum can be written in terms of the Jacobi amplitude function and is thus periodic in most cases, but was never expecting that sort of 'infinite period' may also appear. It was indeed a fun computation. :)

Comment: This solution corresponds to a pendulum that started at the vertical position  in the ancient past, and will come back to the initial position at the end of time. Which is the limiting case of the approximated maximizer you supposed in comments to the main question. You had the right intuition.